# "Cask" as for "coffin"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, american-english, british-english

I'm wondering if the word "cask" in English can be used to mean "coffin".
I know it means barrel but can it be used to mean the thing someone is buried in or you see at a funeral?

Comment: Are you confusing cask with _casket_?

Comment: No, I know casket, but i'm curious to know if cask can be used in a similar way

Comment: Is there a reason why you think cask could  be used to refer to a coffin?

Comment: Shakespeare used ***cask*** Henry VI, Pt. 2 iii. ii. 413   *A iewell lockt into the wofulst **caske,** That euer yet containde a thing of woorth.* But he also used ***casket*** (a "small" cask) figuratively to mean a (dead) body.   King John (1623) v. i. 40  *They found him dead..An empty **Casket**, where the Iewell of life..was rob'd, and tane away.*

Comment: Hello, lch. Have you checked in any dictionaries to see if 'cask' and 'casket' are at times interchangeable?

Comment: Why do you want to use it? As a euphemism or for variety or do you think it means something slightly different (there's apparently a difference between a coffin and a casket)? It's sometimes used, but it probably shouldn't be. There's also a lot of both euphemism and trying to sound posh when discussing funerals, so people may well not want to say "coffin" or similar words.

Comment: I don't know somehow I thought cask could be used in such way, maybe in poems or something. I'm just trying to clear my mind about this but so far it seems I was mistaken

Comment: Maybe it's because of "The Cask of Amontillado" which translates symbolically to a casket for a fortunate wino, reduced to a container of wine himself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary entry of cask does list =casket, although this meaning is 1. obsolete and 2. the only source given is again Shakespeare, who appears to be referring to a jewellery casket (although figuratively):

> Henry VI, Pt. 2 iii. ii. 413   A iewell lockt into the wofulst caske, That euer yet containde a thing of woorth.

So no, it appears that cask is not synonymous with casket, at least not in the sense of a coffin, and never was.

Comment: That's interesting. So colloquially the meaning is barrel, but if cask is used maybe in a piece of poem and in context could it mean casket?

Comment: Only in a piece of poetry from the Shakespearean era.